# GE circuit breakers not fitting in a GE electrical-panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a GE electrical-panel, TLM612S Mod 8.  The panel labeling indicates that GE THQL and THQP breakers can be used, but they don't seem to fit.  The panel has Bryant BR BR120 breakers in it, which do work.  Why won't the GE breakers work?

Comment: Paging ThreePhaseEel...

Comment: How old is this panel?  Are you sure you're just not pushing hard enough? The BRs, being alien, may feel very loosy-goosy, because they don't fit the bus properly. If that sets your expectation for insertion force, you may not realize you need to give a breaker a bit of a shove.

Comment: Pictures would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post photos of this panel please?

Comment: And yes, if you can tell us how old this panel is, that would help as well

Comment: Also, how many breakers are you trying to stuff into this thing?